# Frameworks para testes em aplicativos Android

Tags: android, testes

Não há dúvidas que uma das principais fases do processo de desenvolvimento de Software seja a fase de testes.

Visando isso, por ser iniciante na área de testes, ainda mais para aplicativos Android, gostaria de saber se vocês utilizam algum Framework? Quais as melhores práticas, os melhores tipos de testes para aplicações móveis?

Answer (score 5):

## Tipos de teste recomendados para aplicativos móveis


Muitos testadores têm dúvidas em relação aos tipos de teste que devem ser executados em aplicações móveis.
A cada dia, o número de dispositivos móveis aumenta e o ambiente mobile é relativamente novo se comparado ao desktop. Os testes em aplicativos móveis se diferenciam dos testes em aplicativos desktop, pois a imensa variedade de dispositivos móveis não permite uma padronização do ambiente. Leve em consideração, por exemplo, que existem inúmeros tamanhos de tela e diferentes sistemas operacionais.

Podemos citar 6 tipos de teste que são geralmente executados em aplicações móveis para garantir a qualidade das mesmas:

### 1. Compatibilidade

O objetivo aqui é garantir que o aplicativo interaja e se comunique com o sistema operacional, hardware e todos os tipos de rede de maneira satisfatória. Caso a compatibilidade não seja verificada e atestada com cuidado, o aplicativo pode sofrer de lentidão, perda de dados ou travamento.
Um problema muito comum no quesito compatibilidade diz respeito à conexão com os diferentes tipos de rede. Por se tratar de dispositivos móveis, há diferentes tipos de conexões sendo executadas a todo momento.

### 2. Desempenho

Os testes dessa categoria devem focar na eliminação dos gargalos que provocam lentidão ou travamento do aplicativo. Nesse tipo de teste, deve-se criar situações de estresse, altas cargas e grande número de solicitações para cada função da aplicação. O código deve ser o mais leve possível quando se trata de dispositivos móveis.

### 3. Mobilidade

Aqui se testa a capacidade de comunicação do seu aplicativo com outros aplicativos. É muito comum haver compartilhamento de informações entre diferentes aplicativos e o seu deve estar bem estruturado para uma comunicação eficaz.

### 4. Sincronismo

Esse tipo de teste é relativamente novo e se tornou necessário a partir do momento em que começamos a utilizar a tecnologia de armazenamento de dados na nuvem. Precisamos atualizar os dados em um dispositivo e acessá-los futuramente de outro dispositivo e os dados devem estar íntegros e atualizados. Aqui deve-se verificar se não há perdas excessivas de pacotes e reenvios. Ou seja, verificar mesmo se a aplicação consegue fazer a sincronia dos dados na rede.

### 5. Usabilidade

Parecido com o teste de usabilidade comum aos aplicativos desktop. O foco deve ser a experiência do usuário, a facilidade e possibilidade de realizar as ações pretendidas.

### 6. Funcional

Tão importante que, muitas vezes, foca-se apenas nesse tipo de teste. Aqui, verifica-se se o aplicativo realmente executa as tarefas que deveria, conforme o que foi planejado. São feitos testes com intuito de se certificar de que todos os requisitos foram implementados e funcionam da maneira que deveriam.

Obviamente, há certos tipos de aplicações móveis que necessitam de testes específicos, de acordo com o tipo das funcionalidades que apresentam. Mas, de maneira geral, esses são os tipos de testes básicos que se deve fazer para garantir uma boa qualidade.

Há que se lembrar que não se distingue esses tipos de teste por marca de dispositivo ou sistema operacional. Eles servem de base para testar aplicativos android,  aplicativos Apple, aplicativos em java, windows mobile, etc.

### Automação Android

A automação Android é dividida em duas partes, segundo o [próprio site de desenvolvimento Android:](http://developer.android.com/training/testing.html)

1.Testes Unitários
2.Testes UI (User Interface – Interface Gráfica)

### Fundamentos de Teste

Antes de seguir com a explicação de Teste Unitário e Teste UI vamos conhecer pontos em comum entre os dois níveis de teste.

O Android tem um framework, chamado de Android Testing Framework, como parte da arquitetura de desenvolvimento que nos dá a possibilidade de efetuar testes de diferentes formas na plataforma.

Este framework possui alguns pontos chave:

1. As suítes de teste são baseadas em **JUnit** (versão 3).
2. As extensões do **JUnit** para Android que dispõe de métodos auxiliares
   para a criação de **mocks** e controle do ciclo de vida de um componente.
3. As suítes de teste estão contidas dentro do mesmo projeto em um
   pacote específico de teste.
4. A SDK disponibiliza uma séria de ferramentas e extensões disponíveis
   via Eclipse **ADT** ou por linha de comando.
5. A SDK também disponibiliza o [monkeyrunner](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/monkeyrunner_concepts.html) que é uma **api** para
   dispositivos em Python e também uma ferramenta via [linha de comando](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/monkey.html)
   de **stress-test** enviando eventos aleatórios na interface gráfica.

O diagrama abaixo, retirado da página [Testing Fundamentals](http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/testing_android.html), explica um pouco do processo de utilização de teste na plataforma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A caixa de processo (process) é o coração, contendo a aplicação em si (pacote da aplicação) o InstrumentationTestRunner e o Test package (local onde os scripts de teste estão).

O Test package comunica com o InstrumentationTestRunner, classe de apoio contendo todos as facilidades para a instrumentação e acesos aos componentes. Este comunica com o **Application** **package** para acessar qualquer tipo de componente para a interação (e teste).

*Test Tools* e *MokeyRunner* executam de forma externa sobre a aplicação diretamente no InstrumentationTestRunner.

Para criar testes usamos o conjuto de três itens: **JUnit**, a **Instrumentation** e a classe de teste ( Test case classes) que irá acessar o processo. Também podemos utilizar **Mocks** para este trabalho.

### Instrumentação

É um conjunto de métodos que controla os componentes. Não conseguimos controlar o ciclo de vida (`onCreate, onResume, onDestroy`. [Consulte aqui o ciclo de vida](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/starting.html)) de qualquer componente via API. É através da instrumentação que outros frameworks conseguem “conversar” com os componentes.

### Testes Unitários

Sabemos que o Teste Unitário é importante em qualquer tipo de aplicação, e no Android não seria diferente. Há três divisões para testes unitários.

### ActivityTesting

Uma Activity é algo focada no usuário, logo focada na interação do usuário com uma tela. Ela é baseada na classe InstrumentationTestCase que habilita a instrumentação nas classes de teste.

1. Controlar o ciclo de vida de uma activity;
2. Criar Mocks;
3. Enviar ações de usuário, como digitação e toques;

   Há três formas de testar uma activity com as classes:
4. AcitivityInstrumentationTestCase2: habilita o controle de teste
   funcional dentro de uma activity, geralmente com o foco em múltiplas
   activities.
5. ActivityUnitTestCase: habilita o controle de uma única activity
   isoladamente, onde podemos criar mocks e validar seu comportamento
   no ciclo de vida.
6. SingleLaunchActivityTestCase: hablita o controle de uma única
   activity mas não habilita a criação de mocks, uma vez que ela mantém
   o estado da activity e suas chamadas.

#### Content Provider

[Content Provider](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html) gerencia o acesso a estruturas de dados na plataforma. Geralmente utilizada na obtenção de dados internos, como Calendário, Notas, Contatos, entre outros.

Neste tipo o foco do teste é garantir o isolamento dos dados para que não ocorra nenhum resultado indesejado ou **falso-positivo**.

Ele utiliza apenas uma classe, a ProviderTestCase2 para habilitar a injeção dos dados através de **mocks**.
Service *Testing*

[Services](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) são serviços que executam durante um longo período e não dispõe de interface gráfica.

Através da classe `ServiceTestCase` poderemos controlar o estado do serviço (se este está executando ou não) e garantido a comunicação com outros serviços ou agentes.

### Testes UI

É outro nível de teste que estamos mais acostumados, e não menos importante: o testes da interface gráfica (tela).

Nos itens anteriores aprendemos um pouco sobre testes unitários e como são disponibilizados as classes para ajudar o desenvolvedor a testar o seu código. Mas agora chegou a nossa vez: testarmos com perspectiva de usuário.

Este tipo de teste em Android comumente é chamado de **Black Box** (caixa preta, que é um dos tipos de teste que conhecemos).

Todos os componentes visíveis na tela para o usuário precisam ser acessíveis, ou seja, precisam ter alguns atributos para que seja possível uma ferramenta encontra-los. Na maioria dos elementos os desenvolvedores devem inserir um conteúdo para o atributo `contentDescription` (que seria como um ID externo) e no caso de caixas de texto ( `EditText`) preencher o atributo `hint`.

A **plafaforma** Android dispõe de uma ferramenta chamada `uiautomatorviewer` que consegue analisar os componentes em tela e obter os dados acessíveis (`contentDescription` ou `hint`).

Você pode acessá-lo digitando na linha de comando o texto:

```
uiautomatorviwer
```

ou navegando até a pasta /tools, onde **android_sdk** é o caminho da pasta **sdk** do Android.

Os componentes encontrados, posteriormente, servirão de base para escrevermos o código para o script automatizado na interface gráfica do Android.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

### Considerações

Este artigo teve o intuito de apresentar aspectos de automação na plataforma Android para servir de base a outros artigos relacionados ao desenvolvimento.

É recomendado que você acesse e leia os links contidos neste artigo, que lhe darão uma melhor visão da plataforma e de cada recomendação.

[Fonte: Tipos de testes para aplicações Android](http://crowdtest.me/tipos-teste-aplicativos-moveis/)

[Automação de Teste com android](http://www.qualister.com.br/blog/automacao-de-teste-com-android---parte-1)

Comment: Boa teoria, porém faltou a prática (ferramentas).

Comment: Está na resposta, editei-a. Os tipos de testes não são muito diferentes para aplicações Android.<br>
A ferramenta mais conhecida para testes unitários em aplicações que utilizam a linguagem Java é o JUnit, é claro que tem outras por aí basta procurar, mas a mais conhecida e conceitualmente melhor é a JUnit.

Outra coisa, o próprio SDK disponibiliza ferramentas de teste para a IDE Eclipse, além de que você pode também estar baixando a extensão **Eclema** para fazer a cobertura dos seus códigos.

Comment: Boa, já havia votado antes da edição, agora ficou completo. Pelo que ouvi falar o Eclipse não será mais suportado, sabe se o IDE da Google tem suporte a estes Frameworks de teste?

Comment: Só sei que o JUnit é compatível com o **Android Stúdio**, não sei as outras ferramentas que citei, mas existem muitas outras disponíveis para o **Android Stúdio** como por exemplo o **http://robolectric.org/** e também o **http://simpligility.github.io/android-maven-plugin/**.

Comment: Ótima resposta, obrigado pela força amigo! Conhecia já um pouco de testes unitários o uso da JUnit, mas não tinha o conceito dos 6 tipos de testes que são comumentes executados no Android. Vai ajudar bastante :)

Comment: Que bom meu amigo, todos esses testes deixam o aplicativo mais consistente. Marque a resposta como correta se ajudou você.